# How to get the column values according to id inside blade and controller in Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I am retrieving all Tickets assigned to a user. A single ticket has a foreign key to users table. These are the code below:

```
App\Models\User.php
protected $appends = ['full_name', 'avatar'];

public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
}


App\Http\Controllers\TicketsController.php
 /**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 */
public function index()
{
    $tickets = Ticket::paginate(25);

    $users = User::all();

    //return view('user.tickets.index', compact('tickets'));
    return View::make('user.tickets.index', compact('tickets','users'));
}

Resources/Views/User/Tickets/index.blade.php

            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Assigned To</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
          <tbody>

             @foreach($tickets as $item)
                 <tr>
                    <td>{{ $item->status }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $item->user_id }}</td>
                 </tr>
             @endforeach


            </tbody>

        </table>
```

I want to convert the field {{ $item->user_id }} into **{{ $item->first_name where id = $item->user_id }}** The field should be converted into the **First Name** according to the $item->user_id

user_id is a foreign key to tickets and the equivalent of it is the is of Users table.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly it's not good practice to write db query in views. You can accomplish that by defining a relation in your `Ticket` model class.

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Now you can access user name by `$item->user->first_name`.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I just knew that writing db query in views is not a good practice. You're a genius. You're answer is correct

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 @foreach (DB::table('table_name')->where('id', '=', $tickets->id)->get() as $id)
            {{ $id->id }}
            {{ $item->column_val1}} 
            {{ $item->column_val2}} 
            {{ $item->column_val3}} 
 @endforeach
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.